# Android service Application - CPU monitor

Tags: java, android, service, cpu

I am building an android application that monitors your CPU temperature.
I want to know if there is a way to make class service, and prevent it from being killed, event if my main application is not running.
If it is possible, how?

The service will kick in when CPU reaches a critical temperature and lower the clocks.

Also, is it possible to know if the service is running?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "The service must kick in when CPU reaches a critical temperature and lower the clocks" -- what evidence do you have that you can do this part?

Comment: I am reading the temperature in a loop from /sys/htc/cpu_temp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice:

1. Add a broadcast receiver for "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" and start your service when boot
2. In your service.onStartCommand() method, return START_STICKY to make sure your service got restarted when killed by system.
3. Create a thread in the background to loop and read the CPU temperature and do your work.

More information on "START_STICKY":

```
/**
 * Constant to return from {@link #onStartCommand}: if this service's
 * process is killed while it is started (after returning from
 * {@link #onStartCommand}), then leave it in the started state but
 * don't retain this delivered intent.  Later the system will try to
 * re-create the service.  Because it is in the started state, it will
 * guarantee to call {@link #onStartCommand} after creating the new
 * service instance; if there are not any pending start commands to be
 * delivered to the service, it will be called with a null intent
 * object, so you must take care to check for this.
 * 
 * <p>This mode makes sense for things that will be explicitly started
 * and stopped to run for arbitrary periods of time, such as a service
 * performing background music playback.
 */
public static final int START_STICKY = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you! I have another question : Will the service be killed when i exit/kill my main app? I want to prevent that.

Comment: What do you mean by "exit" app? Normal "back to home" wont kill your process. But if you call exit or kill process, your service will die also.

Comment: I'll just press back while in app; that's what my users going to to.. I need to prevent it from being killed, even if my main app is closed. Is it possible?

Comment: If you are just referring to the "back to home" situation, then you can just stick to my advice and everything should be fine.

Comment: No. I am reffering to the "back" button, that kills the app. I think i will make a separate app that runs as a service.....

Comment: The back button will not have your app process killed. You service is still running in background. And if you do as I suggested, to return START_STICKY correctly, then your service will be restarted automatically even it got killed by system.

Comment: Ok, i got it! But i ran over remote services. Can you give me am example? What are the differences between normal and remote? Thanks!

Comment: Normal service is running in the same process of your Activity(application), to be more accurate, it runs on the UI thread. And that is why you need to create a working thread to do the loop job. The remote service is forked process running in a separated process than your application process.